# Need 2 Decimal Points as Ouput

Tags: oracle-apex

I have listed the attribute of VEGETABLE_PRICE as NUMBER(5,2) in the table under object browser. However, when I run the program and input price as 3.50, it will show 3.5

As far as I know, Precision 5 and Scale 2 will allow me to have numbers up to 5 digits to the right side and 2 to left side of the "dot" eg: 12345.12

What am I missing here? No codes pls, I am a beginner and is only able to click buttons in Oracle Apex so do show me where to navigate to if possible

Input 3.50 --> shows 3.5
Input 25.50 --> shows 25.5

Comment: `NUMBER(5,2)` will store a decimal number of up to 5 digits, of which up to two are decimal places. The format you think you should get is actually `NUMBER(7,2)`, but note: trailing zeros are not stored. But this is all about storage.  If you want a number presented as 3.50 then your presentation code needs to format it like that. How you do that depends on the languages you're using. For Oracle I suggest you search `TO_CHAR()`

Answer (score 0):

It is about column's format mask; set it to e.g. `990D00`.

---

Sample table and data:

```
SQL> create table vegetable
  2  (id    number generated always as identity,
  3   name  varchar2(20),
  4   price number (5, 2)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into vegetable (name, price) values ('carrot', 3.5);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From vegetable;

        ID NAME                      PRICE
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 carrot                      3.5

SQL>
```

In Apex:

[image]

---

Another option is to format number within the `select` statement, e.g.

```
select id, name,
  to_char(price, '990D00') price
from vegetable;
```

In that case, resulting value is a string already so you won't set format mask for it in Apex.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the page in the page designer,
select the Item VEGETABLE_PRICE,
in the properties pane search for FORMAT MASK, choose an appropriate format to display the desired value e.g. 3,50.

that's all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).